# MongooseError: Operation `users.findOneAndUpdate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a problem with Mongoose 5.12.12, whenever I go to the express server on chrome it, I get

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOneAndUpdate()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
```

I am connected to my database as in the console I get "Connected to database" but that's just about it. I login and it gives me the error above. I am quite new to the mongoose package and I'm following a youtube tutorial

Here's my code, src/app.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();
mongoose.createConnection(process.env.DATABASE_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(connection => {
    console.log("Connected to database")
})
mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false)
```

Here is the User schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    discordId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    discordTag: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    guilds: {
        type: Array,
        required: true,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

And here is src/strategies/discord.js

```js
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.discordId)
});
passport.deserializeUser(async (discordId, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne( {discordId} );
        return user ? done(null, user) : done(null, null)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        done(err, null);
    }
})


passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.DASHBOARD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.DASHBOARD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.DASHBOARD_CALLBACK_URL,
    scope: ['identify', 'guilds'],
}, async (accesToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    const { id, username, discriminator, avatar, guilds} = profile;
    try {
        const findUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({discordId: id}, {
            discordTag: `${username}#${discriminator}`,
            avatar,
            guilds,
        }, {new: true});
        if (findUser) {
            console.log('user was found')
            return done(null, findUser);
        } else {
            const newUser =  await User.create({
                discordId: id,
                discordTag: `${username}#${discriminator}`,
                avatar,
                guilds,
            })
            return done(null, newUser)
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return done(err, null)
    }
}))
```

Comment: How did you declare your schema and model? How did you require your passport file? Those are necessary to see where your error is. At the moment, the error occurred because it's not using the connection you declared.

Comment: In src/databases/schemas/User.js `const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({schema})` and in app.js `const passport = require('passport');`

Comment: did u declare mongoose.model and export the model? did you require the model in passport file? As you are unable to show how your files are linked you have to figure out yourself with the tip provided above.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I've edited the post. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Could you try restarting the mongod service and if using a docker container try with a new container. Mostly this error is related to DB Connection and not any syntax issues. To debug you can create an entry and try fetching after saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();

const connectToMongo = async() => {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    return mongoose;
};

await connectToMongo().then(async() => console.log('connected yeee'));
```

This should work because Your model is being called before the connection is established. You need to use async/await with connect() or createConnection(); or use .then()

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue. I tried this, but I'm returned with `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. I tried putting `await connectToMongo().then(async() => console.log("connected yee"));` inside of `const connectToMongo = async() => { /* mongoose.connect* / /* 'connected yee' line */}`. The console.log for 'server running' got displayed but it did not log any message regarding connection to database, nor did localhost stopped loading. It didn't load up anything.

Comment: The web app was running alright just a minute ago. Why is it happening?

Comment: This is the original code in app.js `mongoose.connect(keys.mongoDb.dbURI, {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
     useUnifiedTopology: true
   }, () => {
     console.log("Connected to mongoDb Atlas.");
   });`

Comment: I removed the `document` of the logged in user from MongoDB Atlas manually from their web portal and it's working the way it was earlier. This is a temporary fix, I guess. If anybody comes up with a solution, please do acknowledge.